# Array_intersect an array against a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array 
            (
                [0] => 20
                [1] => 36
                [3] => 42
            )
     [1] => Array 
            (
                [0] => 21
                [1] => 42
                [2] => 30
             )
)
```

And I have a second array of

```
Array 
(
     [0] => 24
     [1] => 42
     [2] => 26
     [3] => 12
)
```

I want to use array_intersect to get the values that are the same from each array. What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to is properly set of the code to do that. I would hope to have this

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array 
            (
                [0] => 42
            )
     [1] => Array 
            (
                [0] => 42
             )
)
```

Can anyone help with the proper syntax or give an alternative option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match your example output, you can simply use a `foreach` loop. In your example, the 2D array is $array1 and the 1D array is $array2.

```
$output = [];

foreach ($array1 as $array) {
    $output[] = array_intersect($array, $array2);
}
```

Note that declaring an array with [] is only supported in PHP versions >= 5.4. For PHP versions < 5.4:

```
$array1 = array(array(20, 36, 42), array(21, 42, 30));
$array2 = array(24, 42, 26, 12);

$output = array();

foreach ($array1 as $array) {
    $output[] = array_intersect($array, $array2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Could you share your output or error? Here's an example from the above code:

https://eval.in/538917


If you don't want to preserve the keys, and need an output exactly matched to your question above, just add in `array_values` before `array_intersect`: https://eval.in/538918

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error, unexpected '[', I have done a direct copy and paste and just changed out my vars and can't get away from that error.

Comment: @ZacPaquette it is probably because your PHP version is older and does not understand the "new" array syntax. Try changing `$output = [];` to `$output = array();`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic is correct. PHP supports the shorthand declaration of arrays in version 5.4 or newer. I'll edit my answer to include the old version

Comment: No problem. I strongly suggest trying to find a host that provides a supported PHP version. 5.3 was EOL almost two years ago. http://php.net/eol.php